# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate with $addToSet pushes duplicate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema such as

```
listSchema = new Schema({
    ...,
    arts: [
        {
            ...,
            art: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Art', required: true },
            note: Number
        }
    ]
})
```

My goal is to find this document, push an object but without duplicate

The object look like

```
var art = { art: req.body.art, note: req.body.note }
```

The code I tried to use is

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: listId, user: req.myUser._id },
        { $addToSet: { arts: art} },
        (err, list) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(400).send()
            } else {
                if (list) {
                    console.log(list)
                    return res.status(200).json(list)
                } else {
                    return res.status(404).send()
                }
            }
        })
```

And yet there are multiple entries with the same Art id in my Arts array.

---

<s>Also, the documentation isn't clear at all on which method to use to update something. Is this the correct way ? Or should I retrieve and then modify my object and .save() it ?</s>

Found a recent [link](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update) that came from [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

Comment: What is your criteria for not being a dupe, i.e. what in that subdoc makes it unique?  `art.type`?  All the fields in the subdoc?

Comment: `type`  is only a schema definition to say that art is an ObjectId. My criteria is not having multiple times the same id in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: listId, user: req.user._id, 'arts.art': artId }, { $set: { 'arts.$[elem]': artEntry } }, { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.art': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(artId) }] })
```

artworkEntry being my modifications/push.

But the more I'm using Mongoose, the more it feels they want you to use .save() and modify the entries yourself using direct modification.

This might cause some concurrency but they introduced recently a, option to use on the schema `{ optimisticConcurrency: true }` which might solve this problem.